# How to sort the checkboxes (checked/unchecked) which is in mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

[image]

```
            <ng-container matColumnDef="scheduled">
                <th  mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Scheduled </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let station">
                  <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="" (click)="getSchedules()">
                  <irg-checked-status [checked]="getCheckedStatus(station)"></irg-checked-status>
                </button>
                </td>
              </ng-container>
```

I need to sort the column based on checkbox selected vs Checkbox unselected.

Comment: Checkbox value will be boolean, is it not working ?. How you added checkbox

Comment: can you add to your dataSource a propertie "select" and change the irg-checked-status to take account this new propertie?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you do the sorting. In general, sorting should be on the backend.
But when you want to sort on the frontend, you can use basic example below:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Sort } from "@angular/material/sort";

export interface DataItem {
  id: string;
  scheduled: boolean;
}

/**
 * @title Sorting overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: "sort-overview-example",
  templateUrl: "sort-overview-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["sort-overview-example.css"],
})
export class SortOverviewExample {
  items: DataItem[] = [
    { id: "1", scheduled: true },
    { id: "2", scheduled: false },
    { id: "3", scheduled: true },
    { id: "4", scheduled: false },
  ];

  sortedData: DataItem[];

  constructor() {
    this.sortedData = this.items.slice();
  }

  sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.items.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === "") {
      this.sortedData = data;
      return;
    }

    this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = sort.direction === "asc";
      switch (sort.active) {
        case "id":
          return compare(a.id, b.id, isAsc);
        case "scheduled":
          return compareBool(a.scheduled, b.scheduled, isAsc);
        default:
          return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

function compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}

function compareBool(a: boolean, b: boolean, isAsc: boolean) {
  return a === b ? 0 : isAsc ? (a ? -1 : 1) : a ? 1 : -1;
}
```

So, in general: `compareBool` will sort `true` values first if `isAsc` is `true`, otherwise it will sort `false` values first.

Enjoy ;)