# Custom sort dataSource of MatTableDatasource : checkbox checked first

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to sort a `MatTableDataSource` in order to display first the rows with checkbox checked then the rows unchecked.

I saw that sorting the `datasource` depends on a `MatColumnDef` header name (id) and asc|desc (start) but this can't help me. I tried to sort on `dataSource.data` because I have the `isSelected`.

Here is what I tried but that doesn't work

**HTML**

```html
<button (click)="sortDataSource('createdDate', 'asc')">
  <span>isSelected</span><mat-icon>arrow_upward</mat-icon>
</button>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()" [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? singleToggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="privId">

  ...
```

**Typescript**

```js
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) matSort: MatSort;

sortDataSource(id: string, start: 'asc' | 'desc') {
  const matSort = this.dataSource.sort;

  this.dataSource.data.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    if (a.isSelected && !b.isSelected) {
      return -1;
    } else if (!a.isSelected && b.isSelected) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });

  this.dataSource.sort = this.matSort;
}

query(q?) {
  this.privs = [];
  if (q) {
    this.query = q;
  }
  this.neo4jService.httpNeo4jRun(this.query, null)
    .subscribe((r) => {
      // console.log(r); // this.checkBox);
      JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r.records)).forEach(node => {
        this.privs.push(node._fields[0].properties)
      });
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.privs);
      if (this.selectedPriv && this.selectedPriv.length > 0) {
        this.selection = new SelectionModel < Priv > (true, this.privs.filter(p => this.selectedPriv.find(e => e.privCode == p.privCode) ? true : false));
      }
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      // this.sortDataSource('privName', 'asc');
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
}
```

For the moment I fire manually `sortDataSource` but ideally I would like to do it in the query method after all records from the server have been pushed in the collection.

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you create a stackbliz  demo?

Comment: Here the stackBlitz link (editor) , i made it run https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-y1a9ws

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort the checkboxes (checked/unchecked) which is in mat-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681099/how-to-sort-the-checkboxes-checked-unchecked-which-is-in-mat-table)

Comment: This is a duplicate, you can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681099/how-to-sort-the-checkboxes-checked-unchecked-which-is-in-mat-table?answertab=active#tab-top